# Got error when updating an observable "roles[0] is undefined"

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this mapping     User * --------------- * Role

Knowing that

```java
export class User
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    roles: Role[];
}

export class Role
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

I want to update a user. Bellow are the required files:

**modify-user.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Role</label>
            <select (change)="onChangeRoleName($event)" 
               class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                <option *ngFor="let role of rolees" [ngValue]="role" [selected]="selected">{{role.name}}</option>
              </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </form>
```

And **user-modify.component.html**

```js
export class ModifyUserComponent implements OnInit
{

  editForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  private selectedRole;
  users: Observable<User[]>;
  libelleRole: string;
  usrId: String;
  selectedRoleUserCompare = {num: localStorage.getItem("selectedRoleId"), name: localStorage.getItem("selectedRoleName")}
  roleName: String;
  rolees:Array<Object> =
  [
      {num: 1, name: "ROLE_USER"},
      {num: 2, name: "ROLE_PM"},
      {num: 3, name: "ROLE_ADMIN"}
  ];

  compareFn(a, b)
  {
    console.log(a, b, a && b && a.num == b.num);
    return a && b && a.num == b.num;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
      this.roleName = localStorage.getItem("roleLibelle");

      let userId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
      this.usrId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
      if(!userId)
      {
          alert("Invalid action.")
          this.router.navigate(['users-list']);
          return;
      }

      this.userService.getUserEntityId(+userId).map(se=> se.roles[0].name).subscribe((response)=>
      {
          this.libelleRole = response;
          localStorage.setItem("roleLibelle", this.libelleRole);
      });


      this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group
      ({
          id: [],
          name: ['', Validators.required],
          username: ['', Validators.required],
          email: ['', Validators.required],
          password: ['', Validators.required],
          age: ['', Validators.required],
          active: ['false']
      });

      this.userService.getUserId(+userId).subscribe( data =>
      {
          this.userService.getUserEntityId(+userId).map(se=> se.roles[0].name).subscribe(name=>
          {
              this.libelleRole = name;
              this.editForm.setValue(data);
          });
      });
  }

  onChangeRoleName($event)
  {
      this.selectedRole = $event.target.options[$event.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
  }

  newUser(): void
  {
      this.submitted = false;
  }

  onSubmit()
  {
      this.userService.updateUsera(this.editForm.value, this.selectedRole).subscribe(data => 
      {
          this.router.navigate(['users-list']);
      },
      error =>
      {
          alert(error);
      });
  }

}
```

And the function `updateUsera` inside **user.service.ts is**:

```js
updateUsera(user: User, roleName: string)
    {
        let userId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
        return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/users` + '/' + userId  + '/' + roleName, user);
    }
```

The update is done with success.
But, I have two bugs when navigate from the `list-users.components.html` to `modify-user.component.ts` which are :

- First issue: The recuperated role is false. The real role is
  `ADMIN_ROLE`, but here I have `USER_ROLE`( It usually shows the first
  role of the list).
- Second issue: I got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFQ57.png) when I select a user from the list of users to modify it (when navigate from list users to modify the selected user).

Could you please help me solving that issue ?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define roles[0].
I don't know why using the first index, because that give you usually the first value which is wrong as you described.
So try `rol: [this.selectedRoleUserCompare.num, Validators.required]` inside `this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group`.

Then replace that on your html file:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Role</label>
              <select (change)="onChangeRoleName($event)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" formControlName="rol">
                  <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role.num">{{role.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

HTH